# Prevent CF7 attachment from being deleted

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using a contact form 7 plugin for an inquiry form and sending the visitor 2 local files attached to the reply email. The function I used is this:

```
function my_dynamic_attachments($cf7)
{
 $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
 $submission->add_uploaded_file('toe', get_template_directory().'/attachment1.pdf');
     $submission->add_uploaded_file('ep', get_template_directory().'/attachment2.pdf'); 
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_dynamic_attachments', 10 );
```

The problem I am facing is that the attachments are deleted from the server after the email is sent, thus they are not available for the next visitor. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it this way? http://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/#local-file-attachment

Comment: Hi kraftner, thanks for the reply! One of the files is dynamically generated from the user input, so that's not going to work. However,I did try it for the second file and got the same behaviour - the file got attached, sent and then deleted from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `submit()` in `WPCF7_Submission` we see a call to `remove_uploaded_files()` which has no filter to stop it. So apparently what you are trying to do isn't meant to be done by the author of CF7.

So apart from getting the author to include a hook there the only way I see is that you generate your file and then create a copy before adding it to the form submission so your original file stays.

Comment: Thanks kraftner! I thought this would be the case. I just commented out the lines inside the remove_uploaded_files() function and it worked... Just have to remember to do it again when I update the plugin :)

Comment: Well that is a really dirty way to solve this. I'd propose to ask the developer to include a way to make this possible. E.g. here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7

Comment: Yeah, I know it's dirty, but I found other posts going back 4 years stating this problem and it seems the dev isn't really making efforts to solve it...

Comment: I've posted the request on the support forum you mentioned. I'll get back to this thread once I get a response from the dev. Thanks again for your help!